# Show one of validation control at same place

Tags: asp.net

I am using two validation control for a textbox and only one will be displayed at a time.

```
<input type="text" id="txtEmailID" runat="server" clientidmode="static" placeholder="E-mail ID" class="form-control" maxlength="100" autocomplete />
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" Display="Static" ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" ControlToValidate="txtEmailID" ErrorMessage="Please enter your EmailID !" />
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator runat="server" Display="Dynamic" ID="RegularExpressionValidator1" ControlToValidate="txtEmailID" ValidationExpression="^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$" ErrorMessage="Please enter valid Email ID!" />
```

I have set `Display` property of one of them ie `requiredfield` validator as **Static** and other ie `regularexpression` validator as dynamic.

I want that if `regular expression validator` is executed than it should be displayed in space reserved for requiredfield validator.

Otherwise if I am setting both of them as static , two lines are reserved for displaying error message which I dont want.

I can't set both of them as Dynamic as there are other input fields for which there is only one validation control .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a ValidatioonSummery. (just add ID, runat="server", etc)

```
<asp:ValidationSummary ShowSummery="true" ValidationGroup="email"  />
```

and in your validators add:

```
ValidationGroup="email" Display="None"
```

Comment: nope , i am displaying error message below individual input fields